# How to avoid the delay for the animation repeat?

Tags: javascript, svg, transform, css-animations, snap.svg

There is a delay starting the animation, is that something issue of javascript code or snap.svg ?

```js
var paper = Snap('#mine');
var strokeHand = paper.path("M116.98 99.756c-4.347 0-6.336 3.407-6.613 5.696l-.022.178v.18l-.12 15.69c-2.794-2.294-4.58-2.86-5.046-2.977l-.19-.047-.193-.024a9.385 9.385 0 0 0-1.142-.073c-2.75 0-4.124 1.406-4.698 2.246-1.676 2.444-.625 5.526-.398 6.12l.11.284.16.26 12.998 20.815c5.61 9.182 14.307 9.895 16.84 9.895.563 0 .92-.032 1.018-.04l.033-.005.03-.004c8.792-1.07 13.16-5.847 15.276-9.666 2.23-4.026 2.43-7.748 2.444-8.16l.003-.058V128.286c.3-3.045-.68-4.9-1.567-5.923-1.66-1.92-3.857-2.072-4.28-2.084l-.078-.003-.077.002c-1.01.02-1.864.216-2.576.5-.522-2.457-2.468-4.685-5.658-4.685-1.012 0-1.9.22-2.656.6-1.193-1.646-3.092-2.442-4.758-2.492a7.51 7.51 0 0 0-.593-.024 6.76 6.76 0 0 0-2.012.293v-8.142c.004-.547-.088-3.012-1.88-4.83-1.122-1.14-2.63-1.744-4.36-1.744").attr({fill: "#E6E6E6"});
var handFill = paper.path("M116.98 102.927c3.12 0 3.074 3.39 3.074 3.39v21.536h2.11v-8.456s.687-2.047 3.065-2.047c.136 0 .278.007.427.02 0 0 2.306 0 2.834 2.247v6.122h2.11v-3.7s0-2.775 2.636-2.775c2.637 0 2.637 2.862 2.637 2.862v5.726h2.11s-.44-4.316 3.558-4.404c0 0 3.296.087 2.77 4.667v11.89s-.484 13.035-14.94 14.797c0 0-.253.025-.702.025-2.25 0-9.422-.643-14.15-8.394l-13.006-20.83s-1.557-4.056 2.143-4.056c.232 0 .483.016.757.05 0 0 3.34.836 8.92 7.574l.176-23.34s.35-2.907 3.47-2.907").attr({fill: "#ffffff"});
var handShadow = paper.path("M94.447 130.662c-.397 0-.793-.148-1.1-.446A10.932 10.932 0 0 1 90 122.304c0-6.07 4.928-11.01 10.984-11.01 1.87 0 3.716.48 5.34 1.387a1.587 1.587 0 0 1 .613 2.157 1.58 1.58 0 0 1-2.152.614 7.813 7.813 0 0 0-3.8-.985c-4.313 0-7.822 3.517-7.822 7.84 0 2.142.847 4.142 2.384 5.633.627.608.644 1.612.037 2.24-.31.323-.724.484-1.137.484M126.206 105.922c-.873 0-1.582-.71-1.582-1.586 0-4.322-3.508-7.838-7.82-7.838-4.314 0-7.822 3.516-7.822 7.838 0 .876-.708 1.586-1.582 1.586-.874 0-1.582-.71-1.582-1.586 0-6.07 4.928-11.01 10.985-11.01 6.057 0 10.985 4.94 10.985 11.01 0 .876-.708 1.586-1.582 1.586").attr({fill: "#E6E6E6"});
var hand = paper.g(strokeHand, handFill, handShadow);
var moveme = [
  {transform: 't0,-80'},
  {transform: 't0,0'},
  
  {transform: 't80,-80'},
  {transform: 't80, 0'},
  
  {transform: 't0,-80'},
  {transform: 't0,0'},
  
  {transform: 't-80,-80'},
  {transform: 't-80,0'},
  
  {transform: 't0,-80'},
  // {transform: 't0,0'}
];
(function animateHand(el, i) {
    el.animate(moveme[i], 1000, function() {
        animateHand(el, ++i in moveme ? i : 0);
    })
})(hand, 0);
```

```html
<script src="http://snapsvg.io/assets/js/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<svg id="mine"></svg>
```

Comment: Thats probably because your first and last elements are the same, so it repeats it (so essentially moves nowhere as its already there). Uncomment the last element, and you will see there is no delay.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var paper = Snap('#mine');
var strokeHand = paper.path("M116.98 99.756c-4.347 0-6.336 3.407-6.613 5.696l-.022.178v.18l-.12 15.69c-2.794-2.294-4.58-2.86-5.046-2.977l-.19-.047-.193-.024a9.385 9.385 0 0 0-1.142-.073c-2.75 0-4.124 1.406-4.698 2.246-1.676 2.444-.625 5.526-.398 6.12l.11.284.16.26 12.998 20.815c5.61 9.182 14.307 9.895 16.84 9.895.563 0 .92-.032 1.018-.04l.033-.005.03-.004c8.792-1.07 13.16-5.847 15.276-9.666 2.23-4.026 2.43-7.748 2.444-8.16l.003-.058V128.286c.3-3.045-.68-4.9-1.567-5.923-1.66-1.92-3.857-2.072-4.28-2.084l-.078-.003-.077.002c-1.01.02-1.864.216-2.576.5-.522-2.457-2.468-4.685-5.658-4.685-1.012 0-1.9.22-2.656.6-1.193-1.646-3.092-2.442-4.758-2.492a7.51 7.51 0 0 0-.593-.024 6.76 6.76 0 0 0-2.012.293v-8.142c.004-.547-.088-3.012-1.88-4.83-1.122-1.14-2.63-1.744-4.36-1.744").attr({fill: "#E6E6E6"});
var handFill = paper.path("M116.98 102.927c3.12 0 3.074 3.39 3.074 3.39v21.536h2.11v-8.456s.687-2.047 3.065-2.047c.136 0 .278.007.427.02 0 0 2.306 0 2.834 2.247v6.122h2.11v-3.7s0-2.775 2.636-2.775c2.637 0 2.637 2.862 2.637 2.862v5.726h2.11s-.44-4.316 3.558-4.404c0 0 3.296.087 2.77 4.667v11.89s-.484 13.035-14.94 14.797c0 0-.253.025-.702.025-2.25 0-9.422-.643-14.15-8.394l-13.006-20.83s-1.557-4.056 2.143-4.056c.232 0 .483.016.757.05 0 0 3.34.836 8.92 7.574l.176-23.34s.35-2.907 3.47-2.907").attr({fill: "#ffffff"});
var handShadow = paper.path("M94.447 130.662c-.397 0-.793-.148-1.1-.446A10.932 10.932 0 0 1 90 122.304c0-6.07 4.928-11.01 10.984-11.01 1.87 0 3.716.48 5.34 1.387a1.587 1.587 0 0 1 .613 2.157 1.58 1.58 0 0 1-2.152.614 7.813 7.813 0 0 0-3.8-.985c-4.313 0-7.822 3.517-7.822 7.84 0 2.142.847 4.142 2.384 5.633.627.608.644 1.612.037 2.24-.31.323-.724.484-1.137.484M126.206 105.922c-.873 0-1.582-.71-1.582-1.586 0-4.322-3.508-7.838-7.82-7.838-4.314 0-7.822 3.516-7.822 7.838 0 .876-.708 1.586-1.582 1.586-.874 0-1.582-.71-1.582-1.586 0-6.07 4.928-11.01 10.985-11.01 6.057 0 10.985 4.94 10.985 11.01 0 .876-.708 1.586-1.582 1.586").attr({fill: "#E6E6E6"});
var hand = paper.g(strokeHand, handFill, handShadow);
var moveme = [
  {transform: 't0,-80'},
  {transform: 't0,0'},
  
  {transform: 't80,-80'},
  {transform: 't80, 0'},
  
  {transform: 't0,-80'},
  {transform: 't0,0'},
  
  {transform: 't-80,-80'},
  {transform: 't-80,0'},
  
  {transform: 't0,-80'},
  {transform: 't0,0'}
];
(function animateHand(el, i) {
    el.animate(moveme[i], 1000, function() {
        animateHand(el, ++i in moveme ? i : 0);
    })
})(hand, 0);
```

```html
<script src="http://snapsvg.io/assets/js/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<svg id="mine"></svg>
```